# How to evaluate this triple integral: exponentials and radicals

Tags: integration

I am solving a physics problem in which I've found this integral,  I tried  but I can not imagine a possible change of variable, probably it is necessary to calculate it numerically..but I would like to reduce it a little bit before to do it.
Thanks for your help!
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2\alpha\sqrt{\rho_2^2+z_2^2}}e^{-2\alpha \sqrt{\rho_1^2+z_1^2}}}{ \sqrt{4\rho_1^2\rho_2^2-(\rho_1^2+\rho_2^2-\rho_{12})^2}\sqrt{\rho_{12}^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}}\rho_1\rho_2\rho_{12}d\rho_1d\rho_2d\rho_{12}\,.
$$

My first try was to define a new variable as $$u=\sqrt{\rho_{12}^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}$$

and in the physics stack exchange forum some one suggested me to define  new variables in the exponential as
$$\omega=\sqrt{\rho_1^2+z_1^2} $$

I carried out the corresponding changes of variables..but it is still difficult to calculate analytically

Thanks again for any idea